# How to remove the horizontal teal line in the action bar when using Holo (Dark) theme?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to remove (or change color) to the horizontal teal line splitting the action bar and the activity.

[image: The line above "wireless & networks"]

Any help would be apreciated,

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the background of the actionbar.

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000")));
```

If you want to change the color you can put any drawable that you want. This tool can even generate a lot of stuff for you : [ActionBar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/).

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. I was looking to do it in XML and your answer led me to what I wanted. I Solved with exactly this code:
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Style</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Style" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/LPT_dark_grey</item>
    </style>`